# Tela preta quando executo uma interface simples feita no Kivy - Python

Tags: python, gui, kivy, tela

Estou aprendendo sobre o uso de multiplas telas no kivy (utilizando o ScreenManager). Contudo, quando executo o código abaixo me deparo com uma tela preta. Não ocorre nenhum erro, mas não consegui descobri qual o erro.

Código TestApp.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

class Tela(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tela()

Test().run()
```

Código Test.kv

```
<Tela>:
    Screen1:
        name:'screen1'
        id:screen1

    Screen2:
        name:'screen2'
        id:screen2

<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'ME APERTA'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen2'

<Screen2>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'ME APERTA DE NOVO'
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen1'
```

Tela de execução + terminal:

[image: Tela de execução + Terminal]

Se a comunidade conseguir me ajudar, o meu futuro agradece :D:

Comment: É preciso renomear o ficheiro kv para `test.kv` com letras minúsculas.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, :D